# How to set the property of an object in an array returned by a getter?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter, getter, setter

With this example:

```js
var data = {
    get names() {
    return [
      { name: "name1" },
      { name: "name2" },
      { name: "name3" },
    ]
  }
}

data.names[1].name = "Yossi";
console.log (data.names[1]);
```

The second object in the `names` array - does not get set by the assignment line (it still logs "`name2`").

I also tried adding a "setter" straight to the second object:

```js
{
    set name(newname) { this.name = newname; },
    name: "name2"
}
```

Same result. 
How can I set any of the object's properties in the names array to something else, in a way that works...?

Comment: Your `names()` getter returns a **new array** every time it is called.

Comment: You need to have names array as property on obj and then use get, set on that same property.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
var data = {
  _names: [{ name: "name1" }, { name: "name2" }, { name: "name3" }],
  get names() {
    return this._names;
  },
  set names(list) {
    this._names = list;
  }
};

const names = [...data.names];
names[1].name = "Yossi";
data.names = names;
console.log(data.names[1]);
```